# How can we do event trackings to the inhouse tracking system with the help of gtm?

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

As I am aware that GTM provides tracking functionality to page to get tracked in the google analytics with the help of HTML classes or ids. But we have an in-house tracking system which tracks events generated on the page. Is there a way to configure the GTM to do the in-house trackings as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Having said that, it also depends on how your in-house tracking system works.

If your in-house tracking system contains JS libraries, you can add custom HTML tags in your GTM. If it just an image request, you can add custom image tags in your GTM to do the work. You can even add your custom javascript codes and manage them to fire on the page as you want.

Recently, GTM launched [custom templates](https://tgupta.net/analytics/custom-templates-google-tag-manager/). You can create a tag template for your tracking tool and use it across your organisation.